# elasticsearch response hits is not showing up

Tags: elasticsearch

I am utilizing elasticsearch and after running a search, this is the response I get

```
{'took': 7, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': 1, 'max_score': 0.2876821, 'hits': []}}
```

My question is why is hits.total = 1 but hits.hits is empty?

Here is the query I used:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
         {"match_phrase": { "theName": "bill" } }
        ]
    }
}
```

I know data exists in my node because when I did the search below (with the same url + index + type in the post request), I got hits.hits to be filled with the result.

```
"query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance that you add `?size=0` to your request? Because that will have as result 0 hits.hits

Comment: Actually the `?from=1` could also cause that issue, and It would also return the `max_score`, so please update your question with the URL requested

Comment: You are so right knetsi, thank you. I had from = 40 when there was not that many search responses hits.

Answer (score 0):

I had from = 40 that was causing the issue.